# Inconsistency in running docker-build on different environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile, circleci, lxc

Locally everything is running smooth and perfect:

- Mac OS 10.11.6
- Docker 17.03.1-ce-mac12

Remotely, on CircleCI it's different:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Docker version 1.9.1-circleci-cp-workaround
- I am using CircleCI 1.0, I briefly tried to used CircleCI 2.0

My Dockerfile looks very similar to this:

```
FROM pensiero/apache-php

# Mostly Ubuntu 16.04 install with some php and node / npm

# RUN apt-get install a few packages

COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN ["npm","install"]
# or RUN npm install
```

And then the chaos is unleashed and all happiness disappears:

```
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.0: ..psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend Yarn and Webpack for *new* front-end projects! Yarn's advantage is security and reliability, and Webpack's is support for both CommonJS and AMD projects. Currently there's no migration path but we hope you'll help us figure out one.
npm WARN deprecated babel@6.23.0: In 6.x, the babel package has been deprecated in favor of babel-cli. Check https://opencollective.com/babel to support the Babel maintainers


# This one is only there from time to time
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'write' of null



npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: lodash@4.17.4 (node_modules/babel-traverse/node_modules/lodash):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chown '/var/www/node_modules/.staging/lodash-23934876/camelCase.js'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: base62@1.2.0 (node_modules/base62):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chown '/var/www/node_modules/.staging/base62-c9d76f67/.travis.yml'

... bunch of similar lines


npm ERR! path /var/www/node_modules/.staging/react-dom-414d50ba
npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! errno -22
npm ERR! syscall chown
npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, chown '/var/www/node_modules/.staging/react-dom-414d50ba'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-06-13T13_25_03_833Z-debug.log
```

The docker info of the environment showing the problem:

```
Containers: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.9.1-circleci-cp-workaround
Storage Driver: btrfs
Execution Driver: lxc-1.0.9
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-119-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (containerized)
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 58.97 GiB
Name: box731
ID: 7CUB:SOW3:C3EG:LNFC:JWZB:O73I:PFPI:4XLM:NXDI:V44F:XEFB:IGTV
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 12
 Goroutines: 17
 System Time: 2017-06-13T15:32:31.903542525Z
 EventsListeners: 0
 Init SHA1: 
 Init Path: /usr/bin/docker
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

The error appearing randomly led me to issue https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/783 which references a bug about AUFS that should be fixed. And it seems that I am not using AUFS ... So it's perhaps irrelevant.

If I remove the line generating the error, I can run `npm install` later using the `docker exec` patch suggested in CircleCI documentation.

```
sudo lxc-attach -n "$(docker inspect --format "{{.Id}}" test)" -- bash -c "cd /var/www; npm install"
```

And it works fine, though I would like to get a build artifact for releasing ... and exerything ran like that is not persisted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is the same thing that has already been reported at https://discuss.circleci.com/t/npm-install-error-that-isnt-reproducing-in-a-local-docker-container/13085. Probably worth following that thread to know when a fix is in place. It could be related to CircleCI specifically.

Comment: Thanks for this ! I didn't find that thread initially, since the `npm install` is happening inside docker I would say that the problem is clearly different. The environments are not coupled if I am correct. What do you think?

Comment: Though, CircleCI implements building Docker in hack-ish ways. They may be doing some special type of Docker in Docker to make it work on CircleCI 1.0 and also use read-only btrfs filesystems which introduce strange issues.

Comment: I have switched to CircleCI 2.0 ... and I don't want to hear about this nasty bug again ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Experienced this issue on CircleCI)

Here is my solution; edit & add these lines to your Dockerfile before any other `COPY`, `RUN` commands:

```
...
RUN install -d -o node -g node /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
USER node
... (COPY, RUN, etc)
```

My container is based on the `node:8.1.4` image. This issue was triggered when upgrading from `node:6.11.0`. If you use a different image then it is likely that the user available in the container is different. In that case you can create a new user or figure out what user already exists e.g. `ubuntu` or whatever.

There are some very creative workarounds out there but this is a pretty straightforward permission issue. Didn't dig into it any further than I needed to but adding `USER` to the Dockerfile was already on my todo list so not all was lost. Looks like a big problem, hope this saves others some trouble.